# Implementing SSE React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Im implementing a notification system for my app and its working well but it is not real time, How can I implement SSE using my setup below

Client Side

```
const [fetchnotification, setfetchnotification] = useState('');

   const getadminnotif = async()=>{

       const api = axios.create({

        baseURL: http://localhost:3000/books,
        withCredentials: true,

        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });
          
       const query =  await api.get(`/adminNotifications?page=${notifpage}`)
       setfetchnotification(query.data.findnotifs) 
  
     }
   useEffect(async()=>{
     
    getadminnotif()
   
   })

   return(
   // here i mapped the fetchnotification array to get the notifications 
   
   )
```

Server Side

here im using express router to get the api calls from client

```
const {getadminNotifs} = require('../controllers/bookControllers');

router.get('/adminNotifications', getadminNotifs )
```

getadminNotifs

```
const getadminNotifs = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

  const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
  const pageSize = 4;
  const skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;

  const findallnotifs =  await AdminNotif.find().sort({'dateAdded':-1}).exec()

  const findnotifs = await AdminNotif.find().sort({'dateAdded':-1}).skip(skip).limit(pageSize).exec()
  const notiflength = findallnotifs.length

  var unreadcounts = findallnotifs.filter(({ status }) => status === 'unread').length
  const pages = Math.ceil(notiflength / pageSize)
  res.status(200).json({ findnotifs, notiflength, pages, unreadcounts })
})
```

what ive tried so far is this but its not working

I changed the  getadminotif function to call an eventsource and then on the client side,instead of using router, i fetched the api calls in app.js

```
const getadminnotif = async()=>{

    const eventSource = new EventSource(`http://localhost:3000/realtime`,{
       headers: {
          Accept: "text/event-stream",
        },
      });
      eventSource.onmessage = (e) => setfetchnotification(e.data.findnotifs);

      eventSource.onerror = err => {
    console.log('EventSource error: ', err);
     };
      return () => {
      eventSource.close();
      };
     }


app.get("/realtime", function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
  });
  setInterval(() => {
    res.write(
      `data: ${getadminNotifs}`
    );
    res.write("\n\n");
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with the SSE implementation? What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? What data are you getting?

Comment: Hello @Bergi, I managed to get it working now, im now receiving data from server periodically after changing the eventsource url to my server url( it should be localhost8080) but the only problem is that whenever i try to call the function in the server  for getting the notifications data that i need in database, (this function returns a promise) im getting [object Promise] in my client side. Heres the code  res.write(
      `data: ${getadminNotifs}`
    );

Comment: What is `getadminNotifs` in that line? Surely you changed that as well, the `asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {…})` you had makes no sense

Comment: getadminNotifs is the function from my controller that fetches the notification data for me, I attached it to the data sent by the sse in server, i dont know if its correct, because the resulting data that i received in client is [object Promise] not the actuall data from my db

Comment: `\`data: ${getadminNotifs}\`` is not even *calling* that controller function, there's no way you get a promise from that

Comment: I imported getadminNotifs from my controller to App.js where im receiving sse request, thats where getadminNotifs is coming from